# VLC play 2 videos on 2 monitors LINUX command line

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command, vlc

I'm trying to write a script that plays 2 different videos on 2 different monitors.
Can't find a clvc command that works for me.
Some one can help?

Able to play a video on the default monitor using:
cvlc --fulscreen --repeat /home/video.mp4
Using Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 0):

I previously used the following to output video on display 2:

`vlc --qt-minimal-view --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=2 --fullscreen file.mp4`

I only have a single display at the moment so can't test if it still works on a recent distro.